# Get the final URL after (lots of) redirection with Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I want to get the final URL after the redirection with just Javascript.

For example I have the url `http://example.com/testClient`, this redirects to different places **with hashes and query parameters** based on client cookies. I want to get the final URL with Javascript only.

The URL redirects to different location, with different hash and different query parameter on different clients based on cookies, user-agent, platform, etc.

This is similar to get the original (expanded) URL of a bit.ly link with Javascript.

Any suggestions on how to do this??

Comment: The question is really convoluted, maybe try and split it up?

Comment: I want to get the final URL after the redirects that take place. Like the final URL of a bit.ly link, similar to that. I want to do this with Javascript only.

Comment: Will it be on only one host?  Or will it redirect to different sites?

Comment: It may have something like a.ex.com to b.ex.com, but will remain on *.ex.com or just ex.com

Comment: Okay, using my best google-fu (I'm a professional) I didn't see anything hinting to a solution.  My best guess would be hack an iframe to give away its actual location.

Comment: It is next to impossible to hack into an iframe. You have a way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iframe like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/qsX6U/

```
iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log(iframe.contentWindow.location.href);
}, false);
```

BUT there is an issue: domain of the final URL has to be the same as the one the script is running on, otherwise it will raise a cross-domain error and `contentWindow` properties would not be accessible.

Comment: That is the problem, the domains are NOT the same. Just the redirecting URL's domain will remain same.

Comment: So i think there is no way doing that in javascript modern browsers, as they all prevent cross-domain access for security. You could maybe bypass this using a server-side script and calling it using ajax, but no full-js solution come to my mind.

Comment: I can not do it server-side way. The URL redirects based on client cookies.